# How can hyperplasia occur in non-fetal hypokinesis?

Tags: cardiology, electromuscular, hyperplasia

I have read that the hypoplasia can occur in fetal hypertrophic cardiomyocytes. 
However, I am interested if this can be theoretically be possible in non-fetal cardiomyocytes which are hypokinetic. I think there must be some growth factors to allow this to happen. Other proposals

- lysozyme, sepsis and cardiac adrenergic neural response / NO / G protein [1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17766478)
- shear-wave, vortex and refolding of proteins [2 Yuan et al.]

### Sources

- 1 [Lysozyme, a mediator of sepsis, impairs the cardiac neural adrenergic response by nonendothelial release of NO and inhibitory G protein signaling](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17766478).
- 2 Yuan. Shear-Stress-Mediated Refolding of Proteins from Aggregates and Inclusion Bodies.

How can hyperplasia be regulated in non-fetal hypokinesis?